# In a IMS network,if a device doesn't get 200 OK for refresh REGISTER then what will be the device behavior?

Tags: qualcomm, ims

During testing, a device sends refresh REGISTER request to network but it didn't get 200 OK response for it. After that device send a new REGISTER request to network. So my doubt is that what device should do as the timer hasn't expired. Is it transmit the refresh REGISTER request untill timer expired or it will send a new REGISTER request.